# Inherit INNER JOIN fields in MySql SELECT QUERY

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization, join, subquery

I want to know how I can join one field of an INNER JOIN table in a SELECT QUERY.

Here's what i got so far:
In this query my result would be NameA, NameB and idC, but i want to join tableA and tableC reference as shown in the image schema.

```
SELECT table_A.idC, table_A.nameA, table_B.nameB
FROM table_Ref
INNER JOIN table_A ON table_Ref.idA=tableA.idA
INNER JOIN table_B ON table_Ref.idB=tableB.idB;
```

My wanted result would be nameA,NameB, and NameC using the idC field in table_A to know which nameC belongs to that idC.

I hope you can help me or give me a reference of this topic :)!

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join on table_C

```sql
SELECT nameC, nameA, nameB
FROM table_Ref r
INNER JOIN table_A a ON r.idA=a.idA
INNER JOIN table_B b ON r.idB=b.idB
INNER JOIN table_C c ON a.idC=c.idC;
```

Comment: (I suggest that "inherit" is not the proper term for database-speak.)

Comment: or if there isnt always a rows to join to in table_C, you can do outer join

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` in `INNER JOIN`
what can happen is to have blanck fields in the final table due to data that are not in all tables